# Is there any possibilty in salesforce to access higher role persons records

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing

In salesforce , by any means, can we provide access for lower profile persons to access higher profile persons records. Whether can we do this by using "Apex Based Sharing" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profile only controls object permissions, there is no hierarchy associated with profiles and they don't control record sharing.

If you want to provide a user with access to records belonging to someone higher on the role hierarchy, you could consider adding a sharing rule, or changing the objects' Organization wide defaults to public.

Apex managed sharing can also be used to provide the type of sharing you described, but I would think that in this situation you would be best off creating a sharing rule.